# Wordpress Hostgator issue sub folder for primary domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a shared hosting under Hostgator with my primary domain **payyanurnext.com** pointing to public_html. In order to make it clutter free while adding other add on domains I told HG guys to make it point to another folder like an add on domain. So WP is currently installed in **public_html/payyanurnext.com** They did it using some HTACCESS code and index.php.

Now the problem-> my admin panel is coming as **http://www.payyanurnext.com/payyanurnext.com/wp-admin/** also linked images as http://www.payyanurnext.com/**payyanurnext.com**/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/vimeo_button1.png

Is it possible to have a normal WP site for me :( ? With link as payyanurnext.com/other stuff.

The HTACCESS in public_html which i pulled through FTP is

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

they also put a new index.php with the following

```
<?php
/**
* Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
* wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
*
* @package WordPress
*/

/**
* Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
*
* @var bool
*/
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/payyanurnext.com/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

The .htaccess file in payyanurnext.com folder is as follows

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want a normal Wordpress site with all the links like payyanurnext.com/wp-admin etc. Even my images are showing like payyanurnext(.)com/**payyanurnext.com**/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/vimeo_button1.png I googled alot and pinged Hostgator manytimes but they told its not possible. Please help me.